# How to edit dynamic form fields to create a single hidden field comprised of the value of two fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to send a form off to where a single hidden field is comprised of two of the other fields that will be dynamically populated by a user (post/zip code and first line of address) where after regular expression only the numbers remain "123|456".

I have attempted to start, using the code below, where I monitor the output in the console. I have managed to dynamically edit a textfield so that all that is shown are the numbers but this is not suitable for a user. So I was trying to store the edited textfield data into the hidden field whilst leaving the complete line of address but I could not see how this can be done.

Also, can someone explain why if I remove the commented line the variable is not stripped of any letters albeit just 1?

```js
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#testMe").on('propertychange change click keyup input  paste', function() //attaching multiple handlers
          {
            var removedText = $("#testMe").val().replace(/\D/, '');
            $("#testMe").val(removedText); //only removes once if removed
            console.log(removedText);

          }
        );
      })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" id="hide" value="">
<input type="text" id="testMe" value="">
<span id="test2"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The question was kind of unclear to me, but I did my best to answer.

https://jsfiddle.net/ccu6j6xu/

```
<input type="hidden" id="hide" value="">
<input type="text" id="zip" value="">
<input type="text" id="address" value="">
<span id="test2"></span>
```

In the HTML, all I did was add another input, because I think that's what you wanted to do?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#zip, #address").on('propertychange change click keyup input  paste', function() {
    var concatText = $("#zip").val().replace(/\D/g, '') + "|" + $("#address").val().replace(/\D/g, '');
    $("#test2").text(concatText);
    $("#hide").val(concatText);
  });
});
```

Then in the JavaScript, I changed the selector to match the new inputs, and then I changed the function.

The first line of this function defines a variable `concatText` to hold the values of each input concatenated with a | character between. Each one has regex applied to remove the letters for the final value. Then the next line changes the value of the span to display, and the final line applies this value to the hidden input.

---

Again, the question was kind of confusing to me, but feel free to comment and I can help some more :)

EDIT: reread the question, I think this better answers

Comment: Darn, beat me to it by a couple minutes. I was about to post my answer, then I noticed you revised yours to very similar to mine. Ah well, I shall not let my Fiddle go to waste: https://jsfiddle.net/ek3s27u9/. OP, you should take note of the global modifier in the regex (`g`), this removes all occurrences of the matched characters instead of just the first occurrence.

Comment: @lucadem1313 many thanks and this does go some way to answering my question. The only problem left is the user who fills the form out will need to see for example the whole address  "1234 the road" when they type it into the form whilst the editing and putting into a hidden field goes on behind the scenes. Thank you so much for answering and adding all this code it is very much appreciated. Sorry my question was so confusing I've been up 2 days trying to fix this.

Comment: @mark.hch Thank you very much - although verytired this looks like the answer to me. I note that you used "blur" instead of "propertychange change click keyup input  paste". Is blur suitable for paste  etc and also mobile devices?

Comment: @user1777582 It's suitable as it fires whenever the inputs lose focus; whether the information was pasted, added by keystroke, or highlighted and dragged (which seems like it'd just be a browser copy/paste action), the data will be there when the input loses focus (like when the user submits a form, or clicks a button, or clicks anywhere else on the page). I use the other event listeners when tracking data live - like if they need to see it appear somewhere as they're typing - but if you don't need to show the data to the user, blur should work.